# Changing List Style Type inside Froala Editor Table not working

Tags: reactjs, list, wysiwyg, froala

In React App,

**Steps to produce the problem:**

1. Add Table inside Froala Editor
2. Select any cell of the Table.
3. Now click on List tool from the toolbar. (Ordered List / Unordered List)
4. Now try to change the style type from the toolbar.

**Problem Statement:**
5. When we tried to change the style type, instead of getting changed, a nested list of same style type gets added.
Even on retrying, which means selecting the style again from the toolbar will again add a nested list of same style type.

[Image shows, changing style type again & again creates nested list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKm3r.png)

**Expected Behaviour**
Ideally, If we are trying to change type type, it should changed the style type we selected.

I tried adding table inside Froala Editor.
Then selected one cell of the table.
Then selected list from the toolbar.
Then tried to change the style type.

Problem begins, when I try to change the style type.

**Expected behaviour:**
List style type should have changed.

**What actually happens:**
When we tried to change the style type, instead of getting changed, a nested list of same style type gets added.
Even on retrying, which means selecting the style again from the toolbar will again add a nested list of same style type.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAGFK.png)